# Nuxt.js: <input type="search"> does not work

Tags: html, ios, forms, safari, nuxt.js

If you write `<input type="search">` in HTML5, the keyboard of the input in safari on iOS is as follows.

[image]

Submit button is "search".
By the way, I am trying to create a search form in Nuxt.js as well and mark it up in component as below.

```
<div class="search-form">
  <form
    @submit.prevent
    @keyup="onKey($event)">
    <input
      v-model="keyword"
      :placeholder="search form"
      type="search"
      @keypress="setCanMessageSubmit($event)">
  </form>
</div>
```

However, the keyboard shows "return" instead of "search" as shown below.
[image]

Why is this?
Is there a way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `action` attribute to your `form` tag.

```
<div class="search-form">
  <form
    action="."
    @submit.prevent
    @keyup="onKey($event)">
    <input
      v-model="keyword"
      :placeholder="search form"
      type="search"
      @keypress="setCanMessageSubmit($event)">
  </form>
</div>
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pompopo/2b0yc6oq/7/